# What percentage or airplanes have engines

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine

I heard that some airplanes don't have engines. how many airplanes in the world have engines?

Comment: A plane without an engine is typically called a glider.

Comment: Do you mean those that do not have engines by design, i.e., gliders, or airframes that have had their engines removed? As it stands it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I would say all of the registered airplanes except the gliders have engines.  I don't know that there is a world-wide registry containing all of them, you'd need to gather the info country by country. There may also be small, unregistered airplanes that have engines. You can download the US list as a starting point https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/releasable_aircraft_download/

Comment: Difficult one this.  Registered aircraft that don't have engines include balloons and sailplanes, but there are also aircraft that don't need to be registered such as hang gliders and paragliders.  Then there are wingsuits, which are sort of gliders with an atrocious glide ratio, and if you include those, what about parachutes?

Answer (score 11):

All airplanes have engines, the definition of an airplane (or aeroplane) is:

> A powered flying vehicle with fixed wings and a weight greater than
>   that of the air it displaces.

There are *aircraft* that do not have engines, for instance gliders.

Comment: Also free balloons.